# Rails 3: Override devise helper method for incorrect email and password entered

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I currently have my `/users/sign_in` path match to `/home/all` . So everytime user looks for `/users/sign_in` he/she is taken to `/home/all`. Now what happens is, if the user enters an incorrect username or password, he/she is shown the error message on `/users/sign_in` . I am wondering how can I show the message `/home/all` ?

Here is my route

```
get "/users/sign_in" => redirect('/home/all')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave the routes as it is. And create a folder under app as `classes` (app/classes). Then have something like

**/app/classes/custom_failure.rb**

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
  def redirect_url
    home_all_path
  end

  # override the response call
  def respond
    if http_auth?
      http_auth
    else
      redirect
    end
  end
end
```

If you wish you can customize the flash message under `/config/locales/devise.en.yml`.

Lastly, make sure to add the below code to

**/config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
  config.warden do |manager|
    manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
  end
```

You should be all set now.